# How to handle file with different line separator in java?

Tags: java, line, separator

I have a huge file (more than 3GB) that contains a single long line in the following format.
"1243@818@9287@543"

Then the data I want to analyze is separated with "@". My idea is to change the default end of line
character used by Java ans set "@".

I'm trying with the following code using "System.setProperty("line.separator", "@");" but is not working, since is printing the complete line and for this test I'd like as output.

```
1243
818
9287
543
```

How can I change the default line separator to "@"?

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("line.separator", "@");

        File testFile = new File("./Mypath/myfile");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        // Process each the line.
            System.out.println(line); 
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `BufferedReader` doesn't use the `line.separator`. The check for `\n` and `\r` seems to be hard coded in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then the data I want to analyze is separated with "@". My idea is to
>   change the default end of line character used by Java ans set "@".

I wouldn't do that as it might break God knows what else that is depending on line.separator.

As for why this doesn't work, I'm sorry to say this is a case of RTFM not being done. This is what the Javadocs for [BufferedReader.readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) has to say:

```
public String readLine()
                throws IOException
Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached
Throws: IOException - If an I/O error occurs
```

The API docs for the `readLine()` method clearly says that it looks for `'\n'` or `'\r'`. It does not say it depends on `line.separator`.

The `line.separator` property is only for developing API's that need a portable, platform-independent mechanism that identifies line separators.  That is all. This system property *is not* for controlling the internal mechanisms of Java's IO classes.

I think you are over-complicating things. Just do it the old fashion way by reading n-number of characters (say 1024KB) on a buffer, and scan for each '@' delimiter. That introduces complications such as normal cases where data between '@' delimiters get split between buffers.

So, I would suggest just read one character off the buffered reader (this is not that bad and does not typically hit IO excessively since the buffered reader does... tada... buffering for you.)

Pump each character to a string builder, and every time you find a '@' delimiter, you flush the content of the string builder to standard output or whatever (since that would represent a datum off your '@' file.)

Get the algorithm to work correctly first. Optimize later. This is the pseudo-code below, no guarantees there are no compilation errors. You should be able to trivially flesh it out in syntactically correct Java:

```
File testFile = new File("./Mypath/myfile");
int buffer_size = 1024 * 1024
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile), buffer_size);

StringBuilder bld = StringBuilder();
int c = br.read();

while(c != -1){
    char z = (char)c;
    if(z == '@'){
        System.out.println(bld);
        if(bld.length() > 0){
            bld.delete(0, bld.length() - 1);
        }
    } else {
        bld.append(z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) `char`  by `char` and [`append()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.String-) it up to a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) until you get `@`

Comment: I hope he doesn't do that like `str += currentChar;`.

Comment: Hello all you guys, thanks for you help and different approaches. If I do char by char, is expected that the execution speed decreases? Thanks again.

Comment: it is not reading character each time from File system, it is reading from Buffer, I don't think it would be much impact

Comment: Thanks so much Jigar, Luis, Munrphy for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A possbile way to do this (*with smaller files*) is the usage of the `Scanner` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final File file = new File("test.txt");
    try (final Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.useDelimiter("@");
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }
    }
}
```

test.txt:

```
1243@818@9287@543
```

Output:

```
1243
818
9287
543
```

But since your file is *very large* you should avoid using `Scanner`, use Jigars solution with `BufferedReader` instead. However, if you have a chance to use smaller files, then this might become handy.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could read the entire line in as a String, and then use the method `String.split(String regex)` which will return an array of Strings.  These Strings will be the numbers between the @.  You could then iterate through the array and print out each number on a line, or analyze the data however you want.

For example:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("line.separator", "@");

        File testFile = new File("./Mypath/myfile");
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(testFile);
        String myString = fileScanner.nextLine();
        String[] data = myString.split("@");

        // Process data
    }
}
```

If you need to convert the numbers to integers, use `Integer.parseInt(String)`

Hope I helped!

Comment: Wow, read in the whole >3gb file and then "copy" that data by splitting this String into an array?

Comment: I know that memory is cheap nowadays, but reading a entire 3gb file to memory? :)